# How do you compute max and unique in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a bunch of documents:

```
{ "name" : "A", "value" : 10},
{ "name" : "B", "value" : 12},
{ "name" : "B", "value" : 14},
{ "name" : "A", "value" : 16},
{ "name" : "C", "value" : 11}
```

I want to find the minimum value for each name, so the result would be

```
{ "name" : "A", "value" : 10},
{ "name" : "B", "value" : 12},
{ "name" : "C", "value" : 11}
```

What is the correct way to do this query in Mongo? I keep thinking in terms of SQL.

Comment: Use the MongoDB [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) for grouping queries like this.

Comment: as @JohnnyHK said `aggregate({$group: {_id: "$name", value: {$max: "$value"}}})` or something like that

Comment: Are you looking for the max of each group or min? Your title says max but your question says min...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the minimum, you can do this by using Mongo's Aggregation Framework with "[$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/group/#_S_group)" and "$min".  Assuming that you had a collection named "myCollection," you could try something like this:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate({$group:{_id:"$name", minimumValue: {$min : "$value"}}});
```